# Angular: cookie service Error Reference: i0

Tags: angular, cookies

This error message in the browser console appears after I added the CookieService to my Angular app: "Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: i0 is not defined." Here is the code related to the cookie:

```
    import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
    constructor(
        private cookieService: CookieService )
    ngOnInit(): void
{
    // Create the form
    this.signInForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        email     : ['hughes.brian@company.com', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
        password  : ['admin', Validators.required],
        rememberMe: ['']
    });
    if (this.signInForm.get('rememberMe').value) {
            const email = this.signInForm.get('email').value;
            this.cookieService.set('rememberedEmail', email, 30); 
            // cookie will expire in 30 days
          }
```

I already rectified the imports and install cookie-service but still don't work.

Comment: Please also share the code of `CookieService`, most important is the `@Injectable()` decorator.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.